# Can I filter logs by user logged in with Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Hi I was researching about filtering logs from Log4j2, I read about its filters, but what I want to filter is those logs made by just a certain logged in user. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with `DynamicThresholdFilter`.

The DynamicThresholdFilter allows filtering by log level based on specific attributes. For example, if the user's loginId is being captured in the ThreadContext Map then it is possible to enable debug logging for only that user. If the log event does not contain the specified ThreadContext item NEUTRAL will be returned.

`keyValuePair   KeyValuePair[]` - One or more KeyValuePair elements that define the matching value for the key and the Level to evaluate when the key matches.

For Example:

```
<DynamicThresholdFilter key="loginId" defaultThreshold="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
    <KeyValuePair key="User1" value="DEBUG"/>
</DynamicThresholdFilter>
```

For More information, Please refer:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html

Happy Coding!